# Python: parse string as time given two possible formats

Tags: python

I have a string `s` that can take two possible time formats:

```
timeShortFmt  = "%Y-%m-%d"
timeLongFmt   = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

How can I safely parse `s` *without* knowing in advance which format it has? I am sure there's a smart pythonic way to do it (probably more than one). I can only come up with lengthy and cumbersome solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fmt = time_fmt_long if " " in input_string else time_fmt_short
dt = datetime.strptime(input_string, fmt)
```

Comment: Great! How wold you generalize the solution for the case there's a longer list of possible formats?

Comment: @Dror: it depends on what are the formats and where do I want to use them. `dateutil` suggested by @Noufal Ibrahim is not a bad option in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [dateutil library parser](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-8d03c6c25ead6f9cab0cde83e6f672b52480ab90). It handles fuzzy parsing of dates.

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("2010-10-10")
datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 10, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse("2010-10-10 13:40")
datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 10, 13, 40)
```